# How to join just first row (stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hi i have following stored procedure which returns multiple photosnames. i want to return just first row. i tried TOP 1 but i'm sure i am making some syntax error. pls help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getProductsBySubCategoryName
    @SubCategoryName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Products.productName, subCategory.subcategoryName, Photos.photoName
    FROM subCategory INNER JOIN Products ON
    subCategory.subcategory_id = Products.subcategory_id
    INNER JOIN Photos ON
    Products.product_id = Photos.product_id
    WHERE (subcategoryName = @SubCategoryName) 
END
```

One more question. how can i select when photoName is null or select a specified record for null photo –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need first photo for each product, try following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getProductsBySubCategoryName
    @SubCategoryName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    ;with ph as (
        select product_id, photoName, row_number() over (partition by product_id order by photoName) pNum
        from Photos
    )   
    SELECT p.productName, sc.subcategoryName, ph.photoName
    FROM subCategory sc
        INNER JOIN Products p ON sc.subcategory_id = p.subcategory_id
        INNER JOIN ph ON p.product_id = ph.product_id and ph.pNum = 1
        WHERE (sc.subcategoryName = @SubCategoryName);
END
```

Comment: you are the best thx :D. and want to ask for a link to learn to write sql script like this.

Comment: It's hard for me to point to some material. Perhaps, if you separately execute statement, which is inside `with ph as (...)` you may get some understanding of how it work, the [with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) itself is just a syntactic construct which is convenient sometimes, but not necessary in this case, subquery could be used also like `select ... inner join (...) as ph on ...` instead of `with ... select ... inner join ph on ...`.

Comment: One more question. how can i select when photoName is null or select a specified record for null photo

Comment: In this case change `inner join ph` to `left join ph`. Additionaly, if `NULL` is not desired in the output list for `photoName`, you can use e.g. `IsNull(ph.photoName, '') as photoName` or `IsNull(ph.photoName, 'No photos') as photoName`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the top record simply by adding "TOP 1" after SELECT. Take a look at this url for clarification: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp. Also can you please specify the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.  
Please correct the following errors and try again.

SQL46010 :: Incorrect syntax near TOP.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE getProductsBySubCategoryName
 @SubCategoryName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Products.productName, subCategory.subcategoryName, TOP 1 Photos.photoName
 FROM subCategory INNER JOIN Products ON
 subCategory.subcategory_id = Products.subcategory_id
 INNER JOIN Photos ON
 Products.product_id = Photos.product_id
 WHERE (subcategoryName = @SubCategoryName) 
END

Comment: SELECT top 1 col1, col2, col3 FROM

Comment: SELECT top 1 col1, col2, col3 FROM this worked but i need all produtcs under subcategory with first picture this gives me just the first product

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification. You'll have to do a nested SELECT statement for that:

    SELECT col1, col2, (SELECT TOP 1 col3 FROM TableName) FROM...